# "for use in" vs "for the use in"

Tags: definite-articles

Which one is grammatically correct or preferred, and why?

- "We developed this algorithm for use in autonomous cars"
- "We developed this algorithm for the use in autonomous cars"

Comment: What do Google Ngram and Google searches for “for use in” and “for the use in” seem to imply very strongly?

Answer (score 1):

The **Google Ngram Chart** is very clear about it:

[image]

Besides, *for use*, without *the*, also feels idiomatic, which is how *use* is actually used here.

Answer (score 0):

I think "We developed this algorithm for the use in autonomous cars" is right. Because "use" here is defined within specific fields-autonomous cars.

Comment: I'd only put *the* in that sentence if I was specifically comparing different "uses" of the algorithm. In general, you'd leave *the* out.